# Overriding Detail View of SObjects for Customer Portal Users only

Tags: visualforce, customer-portal

Is it possible to override the detail page for, say, Contacts only for customer portal users?

Comment: can you provide additional details!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have created VF pages that can direct to the standard view based on the users profile.  Basically you add an action to the new VF page, where if the user matches the criteria, in your case they area  portal user, then it does nothing.  If it doesn't match the criteria, then it redirects them to the standard view.

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact" extensions="myExtension" 
       action="{!if($Profile.Name =='Customer Portal User', null,
        urlFor($Action.Contact.View, contact.Id, null, true))}">

    <apex:pageBlock title="Your page title">

        <!-- Your VF Page  -->

    </apex:pageBlock>

</apex:page>
```

You can adjust this to your scenario, but this allows you to show a VF page for certain users, based on profile, and then the standard page to other users.  Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me. I would modify the condition in the `IF()` with: `$User.ContactId != NULL`

Comment: Glad it helped!